# Trying to create a custom functoid in Biztalk 2010. Trouble getting resources to show (all null)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources, null, biztalk

First time poster here, so if you need more info or when I am too vague, please say so.

We are using Biztalk 2010 here, together with (of course) VS 2010 (Ultimate in my case, not that it matters) on a 64bit server.

I need to create a custom functoid and have done this (enough tuts on the web, albeit usually for older versions of Biztalk).

What I have problems with now are getting the name, tooltip, description and icon to show up when I add my custom dll to the Toolbox. Whatever I try with my resources, I cannot for the life of my have them appear in Toolbox (always null).

Picture link is below, I am not allowed to include more than 2 hyperlinks in my message yet.

I have used this link as (one of my) sources : http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/f843db77-a775-415e-bd08-71c2b1127e40/biztalk-writing-and-usin.aspx

I must be doing something wrong in a stupid way, but I am at the end of my wits here. So, if anyone can please take my hand and help me through this ordeal.. please.. don't let me hold you back.

Thanks in advance !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UAJ6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by the original author (Dennis):

I copied the sample functoid solution from Microsoft into a new project. Used that as a basis to create my own functoids and all is good. Not really the way to go I suppose, but it worked. The reason for my problem (I think) might have been the blank custom tool namespace on the properties of the resources.

Comment: After being answered but maybe helpfull in explaining. The Functoid should have embedded string resources for the Name,Description and bitmaps (icon in toolbox/map grid). If these are not compiled into the assembly the constructor will probably fail when it tries to set those resources (by ID) on the base class BaseFunctoid.
   Hope its usefull although you already have found your work around.